# Lista Lenguaje C

Tags: c

Tengo un archivo de texto donde me indica la patente, la hora de pasada, el nombre y el numero de cabina del peaje por donde pasaron determinados autos.

El problema es que hay patentes que se repiten y necesito que el programa me liste, hasta que las patentes de los autos registrados sean iguales (para que no se repitan) y no se como ponerlo. Adjunto el código de la función listar.

```
void Listar(pnodo inicio)
 { 
     printf("Listado\n"); 
     printf("%-*s %s %-*s %s\n", LPAT, "Patente", "Hora pasada", LNOM, "Nombre", "Numero cabina"); 
    while (inicio != NULL)
    { 
         printf("%-*s %d:%d %-*s %d\n", LPAT, inicio->pat, inicio->pasada.h, inicio->pasada.m, LNOM, inicio->nom, inicio->numcab);
         inicio = inicio->nextnodo;
    } 
printf("\n");
  }
```

Comment: Quizas podrías comenzar por dividir la función en varias líneas e indentarlas, así como está creo que nadie la va a leer. No olvides explicar qué es una patente o cómo saber si dos patentes son iguales. Para más información lee [ask]. Un saludo.

Comment: En otras palabras ¿Quieres que el programa se detenga al llegar a la primera _patente_ repetida y deje de procesar el resto de la lista?

Comment: Hola, gracias. Si, exactamente eso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una manera, ineficiente, pero rápida de hacerlo es, antes de imprimir un nuevo *nodo*, recorrer todo el listado previo en busca de una coincidencia.

Si se encuentra una coincidencia, detener el proceso completo, y si no, imprimir el nodo, por ejemplo:

```
void Listar(pnodo inicio) { 
   pnodo actual, auxiliar;
   boolean repetido = false;
   printf("Listado\n"); 
   printf("%-*s %s %-*s %s\n", LPAT, "Patente", "Hora pasada", LNOM, "Nombre", "Numero cabina"); 
   actual = inicio;
   while (actual != NULL && !repetido) { 
      auxiliar = inicio;
      while (auxiliar != actual && !repetido) {
        repetido = strcmp(auxiliar->pat, actual->pat) == 0;
        auxiliar = auxiliar->nextnodo
      }
      if (!repetido)
        printf("%-*s %d:%d %-*s %d\n", LPAT, actual->pat, actual->pasada.h, actual->pasada.m, LNOM, actual->nom, actual->numcab);
      actual = actual->nextnodo;
   } 
   printf("\n");
}
```

Debes tener en cuenta que el tiempo de este algoritmo crecerá de manera exponencial a medida que aumente el número de nodos en la lista. Suponiendo una lista de 1 000 nodos sin repetidos, para imprimir el nodo 999 se realizarán 998 comparaciones previas y para imprimir el nodo 1 000 se realizarán otras 999 comparaciones.

En cambio, en una lista de 1 000 000 de nodos, para imprimir el nodo 100 000 se realizarán 99 999 comparaciones, para imprimir el nodo 100 001, se realizarán 100 000 comparaciones, para imprimir el nodo 999 999 se realizarán 999 998 comparaciones...

Tiene la ventaja, sin embargo, que no es necesario utilizar ninguna estructura de dato adicional, ni ordenar los elementos de la lista. Estas optimizaciones son necesarias para código que se pondrá en producción con cierto volumen de datos, o para el estudio de las estructuras mismas.

Para que te hagas una idea, la tabla a continuación muestra cuantas comparaciones hay que realizar para imprimir x número de nodos, suponiendo que no hay repetidos en toda la lista, lo cual es el peor caso:

```
nodos   comparaciones
   10              45
   50           1 225
  100           4 950 
  200          19 900
  500         124 750
1 000         499 500
```

El algoritmo es de orden O(n*n/2)

Y si bien medio millón de comparaciones es algo que un procesador moderno hace muy rápido, si sigues por ese camino, pronto se llega a tiempos de ejecución que son inaceptables, dado el volumen de datos.

Una posible optimización, si no se puede cambiar el orden de la lista, es ir creando una lista alterna con los valores ya impresos, que esté ordenada, y lanzar una búsqueda binaria sobre esa lista. El número de comparaciones se reduciría enormemente, alcanzando valores cercanos a O(n)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la resolucion y la explicacion!